# MongoDB: How to move a big chunk of data from one collection to another without interrupting concurrent querying?

Tags: mongodb

I need to move a big chunk of data (100Mb) from FirstCollection to SecondCollection in MongoDB.

Both collections contain millions of other documents that should remain intact.

The SecondCollection already contains similar documents. These documents needs to be removed.

Meanwhile, the SecondCollection is being actively queried by users. The scenario where a user queries the SecondCollection and receives no results or partially-replaced results is not acceptable.

How do I do that?

So far the `$out` aggregation operator seems like a good candidate, but there seems to be no way to delete data within the same operation before `$out`.

```
db.FirstCollection.aggregate([{ $match: {...} }, { $out: SecondCollection }])
```

Session-Transaction way seems to be designed for different scenarios, not for transferring these big amounts of data because the default transaction limit is 60 seconds and it's not enough. Also, this approach requires actually pulling this huge chunk of data from MongoDB to the NodeJS app and then write it back.

Here are some examples of the data in FirstCollection:

```
{
  _id: ..., // just a regular mongodb ObjectId, it's not important
  productName: "Product1",
  productId: "product_001", // persistent unique identifier
  category: "firstCategory", // only "firstCategory" products should be updated
  quantity: 10
  // and hundreds of other changing properties like quantity 
}
{
  _id: ...,
  productName: "Product2",
  productId: "product_002",
  category: "firstCategory",
  productQuantity: 20
  ...
}
{
  _id: ...,
  productName: "Product3",
  productId: "product_003",
  category: "firstCategory",
  productQuantity: 30
  ...
}
```

SecondCollection:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  productName: "Product1",
  productId: "product_001",
  category: "firstCategory",
  quantity: 11 // <= this will change to 10
  // and hundreds of other changing properties like quantity 
}
{
  _id: ...,
  productName: "Product2",
  productId: "product_002",
  category: "firstCategory",
  productQuantity: 20 // <= this will remain the same 
  ...
}
{
  _id: ...,
  productName: "Product4",
  productId: "product_004", // <= this whole document will be deleted, since there is no "product_004" in the FirstCollection.
  category: "firstCategory",
  productQuantity: 40
  ...
}
```

The SecondCollection after update look exactly like the FirstCollection:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  productName: "Product1",
  productId: "product_001",
  category: "firstCategory",
  quantity: 10
  ...
}
{
  _id: ...,
  productName: "Product2",
  productId: "product_002",
  category: "firstCategory",
  productQuantity: 20
  ...
}
{
  _id: ...,
  productName: "Product3",
  productId: "product_003",
  category: "firstCategory",
  productQuantity: 30
  ...
}
```

Comment: see [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)  might be it will help.

Comment: Could you confirm some of my assumptions: 1) there are no other writes to the SecondCollection; 2) you are happy to retrieve stale/previous data from SecondCollection until it is fully updated; 3) you  cannot afford any downtime at all; 4) it is self-hosted non-sharded replicaset running v4.4 of the database. 5) the "similar documents" are the documents with matching unique key.

Comment: 1, 2, 3 - correct. 4 - it's M10 cluster on cloud.mongodb.com, but I can self host it, if this will provide a big advantage. 5 - I can make 99% of them match, but there are also new documents that do not have copies in the SecondCollection or vise-versa.

Comment: M10 is fine, although low IOPS may be a problem. Could you confirm version? There are 3.6, 4.0, 4.2, and 4.4 available in M10. They have slightly different capabilities in terms of query language. The 5 - I was asking about logic that defines "similarity", not the volume. Is it exact copy, unique field match, non-unique field match, a combination of fields match? Which of them qualify as "similar" and have to be replaced with documents from the FirstCollection?

Comment: The version is 4.4. As for the similarity: the SecondCollection contains yesterday's data. 99% of documents in SecondCollection have matching "name" and "customId" property, yet the other properties are different. There are no documents that have 100% equal properties values between FirstCollection and SecondCollection.

Comment: Ok, look, I am trying to get formal definition of what you call "similar documents" because this logic should be part of the query. With this context, would it be correct to assume that 1) there are no more than 1 document with given "name" and "customId" in each collection 2) the documents from SecondCollection will replace the document in FirstCollection when **both** "name" and "customId" match, otherwise both documents will be in the result 3) there are no clashing unique keys for non-similar documents?  May be just add some examples that show before-after states of the collections?

Comment: 1 - correct. 2 - no, forget about similarities. I need to wipe the data from SecondCollection and replace it with the data from the FirstCollection. 3 - ok, I've added some examples in the question description.

Comment: hmm, if you don't need any data from SecondCollection, just delete it and rename the FirstCollection.

Comment: I don't need the data from the SecondCollection within extent of a query, as described in the question. Also, deleting and renaming causes downtime.

Comment: If downtime and partial consistency, both are an issue, why not process and clone the data to an overall new collection('merge_collection') and point your application to that collection. Would that not help? This is considering read-only behavior from the collection for some time. Otherwise replicating the data from one collection to another would mean some inconsistencies(eventual consistency) anyway during the process execution.

Comment: because I need to update multiple "categories" in parallel.

Comment: The only way I can think off is to follow maintenance procedure on replica set members but it's not an option on Atlas. Regarding updating multiple categories in parallel, why you cannot update all of them in a single pipeline?  I tested the merge pipeline on a 100MB collection, it took some 400 millis on M10 aws with 100 IOPS. No indexes, no other queries. I would expect the same time for deletion query. I'd say few seconds downtime is the best option that guarantees consistency.

Comment: Use to migrate chunks, use the moveChunk command.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust all queries to be in transactions using snapshot read concern.

Perform the update in (another) transaction.

https://github.com/p-mongo/tests/tree/master/query-tx-write